# Invalid YGDisplay 'inline '. should be one of: ( flex, none)

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, react-native, webview

getting this weird error when I try to open a post in my app that contains photos inside html webview, the app is a react native app and retrieve posts from wordpress backend

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iis9O.png

changed the view to inline with no success

my webview index.js

```
/** @format */

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  Linking,
  WebView,
  WebBrowser,
} from 'react-native'
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html'
import { Tools, Constants, error, warn, Config } from '@common'
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html'


const { height: PageHeight, width: PageWidth } = Dimensions.get('window')


export default class Index extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    html: PropTypes.any,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { fontSize: Constants.fontText.size }
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const fontSize = await Tools.getFontSizePostDetail()

    this.setState({
      fontSize,
    })
  }

  onLinkPress = (url) => {
    if (typeof WebBrowser !== 'undefined') {
      WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url)
    } else {
      Linking.canOpenURL(url)
        .then((supported) => {
          if (!supported) {
          } else {
            return Linking.openURL(url)
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => error('An error occurred', err))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const htmlContent = Config.EnableSanitizeHtml ? sanitizeHtml(this.props.html, {
      allowedTags: [ 'b', 'p', 'i', 'img', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
      allowedAttributes: {
        'a': [ 'href' ],
        'img' : ['src', 'alt', 'width', 'height']
      },
      allowedIframeHostnames: ['www.youtube.com']
    }) : this.props.html

    const fontSize = this.state.fontSize
      ? this.state.fontSize
      : Constants.fontText.size

    const tagsStyles = {
      a: { color: '#333', fontSize },
      strong: { color: '#333', fontSize, fontWeight: '700' },
      p: { color: '#333', marginBottom: 5, fontSize, lineHeight: 24 },
      em: { fontStyle: 'italic', fontSize },
      video: { marginBottom: 5 },
      img: { resizeMode: 'cover' },
      ul: { color: '#333' },
      li: { color: '#333' },
    }


    const renderers = {
      img: (htmlAttribs, children, convertedCSSStyles, passProps) => {
        const { src, width, height } = htmlAttribs
        if (!src) {
          return false
        }
        const newWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 20
        const newHeight = height * newWidth / width
        return (
          <Image
            key={passProps.key}
            source={{ uri: src }}
            style={{
              width: newWidth,
              height: newHeight,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
        )
      },
      iframe: (htmlAttribs, children, convertedCSSStyles, passProps) => {
        if (htmlAttribs.src) {
          const newWidth = PageWidth
          const width = htmlAttribs.width
          const height = htmlAttribs.height
          const newHeight = height > 0 ? height * newWidth / width : width * 0.7
          const url = htmlAttribs.src

          return (
            <WebView
            renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />}

              originWhitelist={['*']}
              canOpenURL={true}
              key={`webview-${passProps.key}`}
              source={{ uri: url }}
              allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
              mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
              javaScriptEnabled
              scrollEnabled={false}
              automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
              style={{
                width: PageWidth,
                left: -12,
                height: newHeight + 15,
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      },
    }

    // warn(['content:', htmlContent])
    return (
      <View style={{ 
        padding: 12 }}>
        <HTML
          canOpenURL={true}
          html={Constants.RTL ? `<div style="text-align: left;">${htmlContent}</div>` : htmlContent}
          ignoredStyles={['font-family']}
          renderers={renderers}
          imagesMaxWidth={PageWidth}
          tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
          onLinkPress={(evt, href) => this.onLinkPress(href)}
          staticContentMaxWidth={PageWidth}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I am getting this error only with posts that has images inside the webview

Comment: no one can help?!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by using this prop allowedStyles={[]} in the  Component

Answer (score 0):

@Khuser Some of the web css styles are not supported by the HTML Renderer in this dependency that is why you are seeing this error.

Pls check the css styles in the HTML content and then ignore the styles which are not supported, like below by using the prop:

```
ignoredStyles={['font-family', 'display']}
```

This styles will be ignored.

Like mentioned in the previous answer you can also add this prop,

```
allowedStyles={[]}
```

This will help you fix the issue.